# Confusion matrix with wrong dimensions

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, cross-correlation

Good afternoon folks, I'm having trouble plotting the confusion matrix in relation to my data. The matrix outputs a 1x2 vector instead of a 2x2 matrix. I am making a prediction with the logistic regulation model to make a prediction of whether or not you will have a disease. In this case I convert these predicted probabilities into class labels, to Yes or No. The following two commands create a vector of class predictions based on whether the predicted probability of an increase in cases is greater than or less than 0.5 .

```
glm.fit = glm (Cases2 ~ Precip + TempMa + TempMi + umid, 
data = Data1, family = binomial)
glm.probs = predict (glm.fit, type = "response")
contrasts (Data1$Cases2)
glm.pred = rep ("No", 1250)
glm.pred [glm.probs> 0.5] = "Yes"
table (glm.pred, Data1$Cases2)
```

And I get as a result

```
glm.pred No Yes
   No. 979 271
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm a beginner in R!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the process you are implementing so can't advise directly.  However the function `contrasts (Data1$Cases2)` is not assigned to a variable.  So how you intend on utilizing the return value in your follow on sequence is not clear.

Comment: The contrasts() function indicates that R has created a dummy variable with a 1 for Yes, that is, places that may have dengue cases, for example.

Comment: Again, apologize if I have it wrong.  But is the new dummy variable supposed to be attached to `Data1`?  If so, then it seems like a variable assignment would still be in order.  E.g., `Data1$dummy <- contrasts(Data1$Cases2)`  or `Data1$Cases2 <- contrasts(Data1$Cases2)` if the intent is to modify `Data1Cases2` rather than create a new column vector.

Comment: The reason why your are having that kind of table is because all your predictions are NO.

Comment: @SteveM contrasts does not create a dummy variable but rather its a way to check the base level used. eg do `contrasts(iris$Species)` you should be able to see what it gives

Comment: OK, thanks.  So you run `contrasts(Data1$Cases2)` from the console to visually inspect the outputs?

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you very much and you are right ... by decreasing the probability to 0.2 the matrix emerged! But this is not good right?

Comment: Yeah. Your logit function cannot be able to distinguish between yes and no. Try other methods. eg svm, LDA etc

Comment: Maybe these are your results? Maybe you don't have predicted yes values according to your logistic regression

Comment: Exactly, to create the confusion matrix with all the data, you have to put a probability of 0.2. In this case, the accuracy as well as other evaluation methods of the model are terrible. I am thinking of a more suitable model for this database. Accepting suggestions, since the bank has 85% NO and 15% YES.